# Simple application to view emails in the SMTP Pickup Directory

Tags: asp.net, testing, email-client

I am looking for a web application to view email files in a folder for use in a test environment. If required I will write the web application myself, but I was hoping someone has already written one.

The reason we need this is because our test environment deliberately does not send emails, but we still need to check our website is writing the correct emails to the SMTP Pickup Directory.

I have heard such web applications exist, and even spoken to people that have used them, but I cannot find one.

Requirements:

- Must be web based.
- Shows list of emails based on files in a folder.
- Allows user to read individual emails
- Allows user to delete individual emails.
- Allows user to delete all emails.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to find an existing application which does this?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: No. I thought it would be easy to find, but so far have found nothing, My initial reaction is to write it myself, but I would rather use an existing app.